# How can I do drop caps in Tinymce Editor?

Tags: tinymce, editor, tinymce-4, rich-text-editor

​I use ASP.NET MVC Project and has here Tinymce plugin editor

Choosing character by shortcut format or choosing character by custom button.

How can I do **Drop Caps** ?

[Sample Photo](https://pasteboard.co/HqXy6T7.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make that by wrapping the first letter with `<span class="drop-cap">`.
Alternatively use `<span class="drop-cap drop-cap-reversed">` for reversed color.

```css
.drop-cap {
    float: left;
    padding: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    font-family: Georgia;
    font-size: 60px;
    line-height: 50px;
    color: #263238;
}
.drop-cap-reversed {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #263238;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<p>
<span class="drop-cap">L</span>ed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi. Nulla quis semat nibh elementum imperdiet. Duis sagittis ipsum. Praesent mauris. Fusce nec tellus sed augue semper porta. Mauris massa. Vestibulum lacinia arcu eget nulla. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Curabitur sodales ligula in libero. Vestibulum lacinia arcueget nulla. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Curabitur sodales ligula in libero. Sed dignissim lacinia nunc.sed cursus antedapibus diam. Sed nisi. Nulla quis sem at nibh elementum imperdiet.Sed dignissim lacinia nunc.sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi. Nulla quis sem at nibh elementum imperdiet.Vestibulum lacinia.
</p>
<span class="drop-cap drop-cap-reversed">L</span>ed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi. Nulla quis semat nibh elementum imperdiet. Duis sagittis ipsum. Praesent mauris. Fusce nec tellus sed augue semper porta. Mauris massa. Vestibulum lacinia arcu eget nulla. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Curabitur sodales ligula in libero. Vestibulum lacinia arcueget nulla. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Curabitur sodales ligula in libero. Sed dignissim lacinia nunc.sed cursus antedapibus diam. Sed nisi. Nulla quis sem at nibh elementum imperdiet.Sed dignissim lacinia nunc.sed cursus ante dapibus diam. Sed nisi. Nulla quis sem at nibh elementum imperdiet.Vestibulum lacinia.
</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do it but they all require some level of CSS.  This page shows two good examples:

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/drop-caps/

You can use `style_formats` in TinyMCE to allow people to apply a class to text.  You can use `content_css` to pass CSS to the editor that will then render that content as you want it based on the applied class.

Comment: FİDDLE example possible here ?